# Extracting AD subgroups information

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I need to extract AD groups and all of it's subgroup into an excel sheet.Basically the script should loop though each of the AD group and get their subgroup.

AD_Group      Subgroup
----------    ---------

I'm new to PowerShell so any script to acheive the expected result should be helpful.